# Easier way for conditional string op?

Tags: bash

Supposed i have a variable

```
A_LOSS="5%"
```

I need to append as part of larger command (`tc`) if it can evaluate ala.

```
if [ -n $A_LOSS ]
then A_LOSS="loss $A_LOSS"
fi
```

Since I have a lot of these cases it quickly becomes rather verbose, so is there a smarter way or should I maybe just make a function for that ?

Comment: Aside: Usually, you want an array instead of a string if you're building lists of words (assuming those lists will eventually be used as argument lists; `someprog $some_args` [has major bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); `someprog "${some_args[@]}"` can correctly handle a wider array of possible argument lists).

Comment: `[[ -n $A_LOSS ]] && A_LOSS="loss $A_LOSS"` is the shortest thing that's going to be idiomatic. Whether that's short and readable enough for you is really a question _for you_.

Comment: (...that said, the all-caps variable namespace is standard-defined as used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS-provided tools; if you want a guarantee that your variable names won't have unintended effects on shell behavior, use names with at least one lower-case character -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Comment: Can you give example of other variables ? Is it always the same strings ("Loss ") that will be used as a prefix ?

Comment: I'm voting-to-close as opinion-based because asking for something "smarter" or "easier" without a specific problem that updated code would solve is broad and opinion-based in the same way that questions about what constitutes "best practice" are. See [Why is asking a question on best practice a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing)

Comment: (Now, "how can I write a function that, given a variable name and a string, prepends the string to the variable?" would be a much more actionable question, particularly if the code needed to be compatible with versions of bash from before namerefs were introduced -- [indirect reference and assignment](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) used to be points of significant complexity).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is fair enough. It just happended I knew there was a shortcut somehow which is why I asked - It's important to not bloat your code when there is a already a feature in the language that can accomplish it - so I honestly think this is not the same as asking for best practices (which tend to get opinion based).

Comment: The answer you accepted _isn't_ identical to the behavior in of the code this question asks for an equivalent to. You asked how to _modify_ the variable `A_LOSS`; you accepted an answer teaching how to expand to either a nothing (if the variable is unset), or a value with a prefix, without modifying the original variable's value at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's just re-assigning thats left out,so I guess you are right. Feel free rephrase the question though.

Comment: If I rephrased the question to match the accepted answer by Bentoy13, it would no longer match the answer by dash-o (who is, IMHO, more accurately giving you what you asked for, even if that differs from what you _actually wanted_).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy last part of my question, im actually putting less value on creating a function - so there you have it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a function, bash gives you [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMALTV):

```
${A_LOSS:+"loss $A_LOSS"}
```

However, it can be cumbersome if you have a lot of options.

Comment: Exactly what I needed / was looking for. Also can just overwrite variable or make new ones if it gets too cumbersome to have it all in one line.

Answer (score 2):

On surface, the goal is to reduce the verbosity of a code that check multiple variables for a content, and then prepend a prefix ("loss " in this case) to any non-empty variable.

Possible to create a function for this task, that will take a variable name, and a prefix (assuming different prefixes for different variables). Using the 'reference' variable (declare -n) make the function take variable "by reference".

```
function add_prefix {
    declare -n ref=$1
    declare prefix=$2
    [ -n "$ref" ] && ref="$prefix $ref"
}

add_prefix A_LOSS "Loss "
add_prefix A_GAIN "Gain "
...
```

As per comment from Charles Duffy: the 'reference' variable is relatively new feature to bash. It is available in 4.4 (Mint 19.2), but not in 4.1. On older version, possible to use indirect references. If running  older version, the following substitution will work:

```
function add_prefix {
    local ref=$1 prefix=$2
    [ -n "${!ref}" ] && read "$ref" <<< "$prefix ${!ref}"
}
add_prefix A_LOSS "Loss "
add_prefix A_GAIN "Gain "
```

Comment: [_grumbles about legacy-ksh function declaration syntax_](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

Comment: BTW, you might want to specify the minimum version needed for the above code to work, as some major OS vendors (_ahem_ Apple _ahem_) are still shipping releases prior to same.

Comment: `declare -n` was [introduced in Bash 4.3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061).